# Connecting User ID to Search Report Results

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, powershell, search-results, sql-server

SharePoint 2013 allows the search reports to be pulled from site collection level by month and day. The report is helpful but I want to know who did the search.  The report seems inaccurate because the same person could of searched all day and all of the results could be connected to them.

Question. Is there way that I can retrieve search reports but list too the person who completed the search for that search topic? For example,

**Search Topic: Food  | User ID: jdoe**